# I wrote a line to display hello in pygamezero but instead its showing white blocks instead of texts

Tags: python, pgzero

i executed the following code

```py
def draw():
    screen.draw.text("hello", topleft=(10 , 10))
```

but the output I get is just 5 white blocks instead of hello
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYB1J.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) script looks as follows:

```py
import pgzrun

def draw():
    screen.clear()
    screen.draw.text("hello", topleft = (10, 10))

pgzrun.go()
```

You have to call [`pgzrun.go()`](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ide-mode.html) **after** the definition of the [`draw`](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html#creating-a-window) function.